# install jdk6 on ubuntu 12.04, can use it in root user but can't in normal user

Tags: java, jdk

I am trying to install jdk-6 in ubuntu 12.04. I put the folder in `/opt` and set the environment path:

```
vim /etc/profile
vim /etc/bash.bashrc
```

add this to both of the files:

```
#set java environment
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_37
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_37/jre
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I change the user status to `root user`so I have the authority to edit the file. After that, I use `java -version` to check the result, it works fine in `root user` status:

```
root@brendon-Lenovo:/home/brendon# java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

But when I change back to normal user, I can't find the jdk I've installed:

```
brendon@brendon-Lenovo:~$ java -version
程序 'java' 已包含在下列软件包中：
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

I check the profile and bash.bashrc, both of them are modified, so I really have no idea why can't I use jdk-6 in my normal status.

Does anyone know why?

---

I have tried

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/[java folder name]
sudo chown -R [username] /opt/[java folder name]
```

Then I check the `java -version`, anyway, it doesn't work.

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre ?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you don't have access to /opt/java folder as normal user. Try below commands and then try to access:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/[java folder name]
sudo chown -R [username] /opt/[java folder name]
```

In case you are willing to try another method. I use it and it works all the time.

1. Download the latest Java SE SDK version.

   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/ja...ads/index.html
2. Untar the Archive

   ```
   tar -xzvf /root/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.tar.gz

   mv jdk1.7.0_17 /opt

   cd /opt/jdk1.7.0_17
   ```
3. This step registers the downloaded version of Java as an alternative, and switches it to be used as the default:

   ```
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java 1
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac 1
   update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1
   update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java
   update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac
   update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
   ```
4. Test

   To check the version of Java you are now running

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   To check the browser plugin browse to http://www.java.com/ and click “Do I have Java?”

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited the answer above in case you are willing to try another way of installing java.